# Maven Multi-Project is not Deployed Correctly to Maven Central

Tags: java, maven, build, multi-module, maven-central

I have a project (cc.renken.pipeio) at maven central. Previously, it was a simple maven-project and upload worked fine. Later on I changed it into a multi-module project with the configuration found below.

[main project pom](https://gitlab.com/funsheep/pipeio/blob/develop/pom.xml)

[submodule pom](https://gitlab.com/funsheep/pipeio/blob/develop/core/pom.xml)

The build process is done by calling

```
mvn package deploy
```

However, now only the main project (pipeio) is uploaded (the .pom files), the javadoc and source code from the submodules are generated in the target folders within the submodules. But these are not uploaded. What am I missing in the configuration?

Comment: First I have to say that what you have claimed having a multi module build is not correct cause the version in the different modules (core: 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT instead of 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT of the parent) are not in line with the parent or vice versa. So in the end all your modules as well as the parent must have the same version for a multi module build and to deploy/release them at the same time (which makes sense in your case). Apart from that can you please add a log output of the things which is not working...

Comment: Furthermore I would recommend to remove all ide specific things from your repository like `.settings`, `.classpath`, `.project`...more things coming into my mind: You are defining several plugins directly instead of using pluginManagement etc. but you missed many plugin you have not defined like maven-compiler-plugin, maven-resources-plugin, maven-install-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin to use things like deployAtEnd etc.

Answer (score 0):

Found out, that it was a caching problem in the definition of the gitlab-build script. I accidently cached the .git/ repositories which led to overwriting the actual .git/ repositories. This led to side effects, where the submodules where not build because they just weren't there. After correcting the cache settings everything works fine now.

So this problem is not maven or maven multi-project related actually.